How Do I Finish My Fence Section Next to Garage
I need some advice on finishing a fence section next to my attached garage. Here's the situation:

Neighbor and I split the cost to build a fence.
I have a section of fence next to my garage that's incomplete, about 30 inch gap.
Neighbor suggested attaching a 2x4 to the garage and completing the horizontal fence section by fixing it to the 2x4.
The fence post near the garage is just for the gate latch, so not much weight is expected.

I'm unsure if this is a good idea or how to do it properly. Maybe there is a way to just finish the section beside it without touching the garage? I live in Canada, where ground freeze/thaw cycles can be harsh. Any ideas on how to finish the fence would be greatly appreciated.
Pics:
https://imgur.com/a/Yti4XWq

This is not complicated and there is no "Magic" solution.  You have 2 choices.  Attach to the wall as you neighbor suggested, or put a post next to the garage. It's your choice, we cannot make that decision for you.

Appreciate your reply. If I attach to the garage and it shifts as usual during the winter, isn't there a risk of damaging both the garage and the fence?

How much shifting do you get?  wood is somewhat forgiving.  You have the outside post that is the latch side of the gate.  That gap is most likely to alter, you won't have something like the garage wall rupturing.

You neighbor live right next door. He has experienced the winters. Take his advice he knows more of what the weather does than people on the internet.

Really good points. Thanks again.
